# Is it possible to change the spacing between particular columns of a table?

Tags: spacing, longtable, columns

I am struggling to make a longtable fit on A4 pages in portrait mode. The problem is that the table is too wide. I am not allowed to use smaller fonts (that would solve my problem but it's not an option), and \tabcolsep nearly does it, but it shrinks the distance between columns globally and with my particular table I end up with columns that are almost overlapping each other, while there are several others where there still is plenty of space between them. If I could reduce the space just between those particular columns, the table would fit. Is there a way to do this without changing the spacing between ALL columns (since that would make the table unreadable, its content would overwrite itself)?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
c@{}c
```

Is two centred columns with no space between them the default space is equivalent to

```
c@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}
```

so you can use any space you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know this trick, and it's just what I needed!